# Ajax call to drupal module not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I have written a module in drupal in which the .js file calls drupal .module file via ajax . But for some reasons the ajax call is not working . Please help

Here is my .js file

```
// Jquery wrapper for drupal to avoid conflicts between libraries.
(function ($) {
  // Jquery onload function.

Drupal.behaviors.ajax_privacy = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
// Your JS code.

$.get('ajax/call',null,ajaxAction);
return false;
}
};

ajaxAction=function(response)
  {
  alert(response);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And here is my .module file

```
<?php

/**
* Implementation of hook_init().
*/
function ajax_privacy_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','ajax_privacy').'/userprivacy.js');
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function ajax_privacy_menu() {

  $items = array();  

  $items['ajax/call'] = array(
    'title' => 'menu privacy',
    'page callback' => 'ajax_privacy_get_html', // Render HTML
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback to return JSON encoded data.
 */
function ajax_privacy_get_html() {

  return drupal_json('hi');
}
```

Comment: I think `drupal_json` is a drupal 6 function, changed to `drupal_json_output` in drupal 7. Try that.

Comment: I tried replacing drupal_json with drupal_json_output . Still no change

Comment: Is this because of clean_urls ? I have disabled clean_urls feature due to some reason

Comment: use the browser console to test and watch what is happening. What happens if you just point the browser to ajax/call ?

Comment: It worked !! Thanks...But now I am getting full html instead of only json data . I tried drupal_json_output but no use

Comment: just call drupal_json_output(), remove the return. You can always just look at code of how another module does it. eg [Ajax blocks module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ajaxblocks/tree/ajaxblocks.module)

Comment: Do not return drupal_json_output()

Answer (score 1):

Add access callback at true

```
 $items['ajax/call'] = array(
    'title' => 'menu privacy',
    'page callback' => 'ajax_privacy_get_html', // Render HTML
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
```